# check process status after _spawnvp(_P_NOWAIT, ... )

Tags: c, windows

I have started in Windows a sub process using `_spawnvp(_P_NOWAIT, ... )`. This sub process communicates to the parent by a set pipes obtained by calls to `_pipe()` performed before the `_spawn` call.

How do I check the status of the sub process from the parent? I especially would like to know whether the sub process failed and exited. I have seen that `_cwait()` can be used to the process handle obtained by `_spawn()`, but `_cwait()` seems to block until the sub process exits -- I just want to see the sub process is still alive, and has not crashed or failed to start up at all.

Comment: Run `cwait()` in a thread.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work -- thanks!